# Launch Screen Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

## My problem is :

I have deleted **LaunchXIB** because of a code moving from **iOS7.0** to **iOS8.0**.

But in my **Images.xcassets** all required images are present in **LaunchImage**. but in my older app has a welcome screen which has same like **launchImage** but now its not matching with **LaunchImage**. so how can I handle it to look like same???
please any one handle this scenario then please share it with me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this web service : [Link](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/) to create an (image set/LaunchImage) from one image.

In the .xassets you need to add a launchImage (by pressing on the '+' sign in the lower-left). Then add the images created from the web service

x1 images are for non retina display devices

x2 images are for retina display images

x3 images are for iPhone 6 plus

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have same issue...

Just delete `LaunchImage.xib` clean all targets and execute your code, surely this was working very well.

Make sure all the LaunchImages are present in `Images.xcassets` or Resource directory.

Comment: working but on **iPhone6** and **iPhone6 Plus** the welcome screen will be blur...

Comment: you have to put Launch Images for that as well in Images.xcassets

Comment: iphone 6 size : 750 × 1334  iphone6 plus size : 1242 × 2208 put this both size image

Comment: I already mentioned that...I tried that...and now I have correct sizes of image in the block which is required....

Comment: your iPhone 6/6+ images are under the "Launchimage" or just adding out side of it?